# Synchronization two different slideshow jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

please go to this Address:
http://pakianco.ir/test/index.php

on the above of  page i use two different slideshow for displaying company products. these two slideshow must be consonant means that they must be start at same time and images used in two slideshow must be change Simultaneously.But it did not happen.

i use two different plugin for that. left slideshow is bootstrap carousel plugin and right slideshow is [flux Slider](http://www.joelambert.co.uk/flux/).

this code is for right slideshow:

```
 $(function(){
            window.myFlux = new flux.slider('#slideshow', {
                autoplay: true,
                pagination: false,
                transitions: ['blocks'],
                delay: 5000
            });
        });
```

and this is for left slideshow:

```
$('#slides.carousel').carousel({
  'interval': 5000,
  'pause':'false',
      'wrap':'false'
});
```

can you help me to doing that

Comment: Why not use one plugin? Slideshows aren't very hard, you could easily write your own script to do exactly what you want. Have one function run both slideshows to insure they will go at the same time.

Comment: our client wanted us to use block effect of flux slider jquery plugin on right images that created some blocks.